# Store file on hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to store some .tbl files in hadoop.

I am using this command: `hadoop fs -put customer.tbl`

But Im getting:

```
Usage: java FsShell [- put <localsrc> .. <dst>]
```

If I do `hadoop fs -cat cusomer.tbl`

It appears that file does note exist.

Comment: Please edit your question with the result of just `ls -l` in the directory you are running this command from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to provide local-src and HDFS-dst.
Can you try to add destination?
e.g. `hadoop fs -put customer.tbl .`

please also try execute "ls" on the HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

please also try execute "ls" on the HDFS using hdfs command, 'hdfs' should be found under hadoop-version-number/bin/:

```
hdfs dfs -ls
```

Comment: Thanks! Now appears "put: file customer.tbl does not exist".

Comment: please confirm that "customer.tbl" exists in the source directory. i.e. execute "ls -l  customer.tbl" before you execute the "hadoop fs -put customer.tbl"

Comment: Thanks again. It exists, when I execute that command it appears: -rw-rw-r--. 1 hadoop hadoop .. customer.tbl. It seems that exists. But it appears that the owner of the file is hadoop and Im logged with username hadoopadmin, can be because of this?

Comment: it seems like you have read permission for the file - which is good enough. The file rights doesn't seems to be the problem

Comment: please try executing ls on the HDFS- using: **hadoop fs -ls**

Comment: I change the ownership of the customer.tbl to hadoopadmin. But it says again that "put: file customer.tbl does note exist"

Comment: The "hadoop fs -ls" command shows: "ls: cannot acess .: No such file or directory"

Comment: this looks like you have some basic problems with your hadoop file system. did you install hadoop by yourself? did "hdoop fs -ls" ever work for you? which version of hadoop are you using? please try executing hdfs dfs -ls

Comment: @codin `hdfs dfs - ls` without the destination folder will look for a home directory on HDFS for the user currently executing the command. For example, your username is bob. Run that command, the error means `/user/bob/` doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, I installed the version 1.2.1. The command "hadoop fs -ls" shows "ls: cannot acess .: No such file or directory. But the command "hadoop fs -ls /" shows: 
drwxrwxrwx - hadoopadmin supergroup 0 /date/date/date /tmp
drwxr-xr-x - hadoopadmin supergroup 0 /date/date/date /user

Comment: @codin I meant user folder above. If you do `hdfs dfs -ls /user` you'll see no `hadoopadmin` folder there. You need to do `hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hadoopadmin/`

Comment: okay great, what is the output of  **"hadoop fs -ls ."**? (should show the content of the current directory in HDFS)

Comment: try also: **hadoop fs -put customer.tbl /user/hadoopadmin** (after you created this folder using -mkdir)

Comment: The "hdfs dfs -ls command" shows "bash: hdfs: command not found".

Comment: I tried "hadoop fs -put customer.tbl /user/hadoopadmin" after create the folder. But again it shows "put: file customer.tbl does not exist"

Comment: can you give the full path name of the customer.tbl file to the hadoop fs -put command? (e.g. hadoop fs -put /tmp/customer.tbl /user/hadoopadmin)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working now.  The hadoop dfs -put customer.tb /user/hdadmin worked! Your solution works fine, the problem was some distraction I guess, because it seems that I was doing that command in hadoop acount and not in hadoopadmin account, and the file was in the direcory of hadoopadmin user. But its strange because when I did ls command the file "customer.tbl" appears. But I change now to hadoopadmin and the command works. Thanks for your help. By the way, the /user/hadoopadmin it is a good directory to store this files? (Im starting learning hadoop)

Comment: You are using very old version of hadoop. I'd suggest considering using more up-to-date version of hadoop (http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html)

Comment: regarding folder name - I'd use foldername which meaningful name

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help and tips!

Comment: @codin I normally put files that I want to be used by all users in `/tmp` instead of the user folders